# How to stop my child from creating new accounts on Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-one

Okay, I set-up parental control for my child's Xbox One that I bought him and set it to teen settings. It works fine but there is a flaw, my child can just make another account and by-pass this and make a new unrestricted account.

I have caught him several times making new accounts and I had to delete them (you know how teens are).

Is there anyway to stop them from doing it or a way to NOT allow new accounts? I hope there is as I don't want my son downloading things or watching things he shouldn't. If there isn't an option for this than I will have to return it!

Comment: Sitting down and talking with your child is the best solution imo. Blocking something will turn into a war (you block, your child bypasses, rinse and repeat), but talking with your child won't. If you need help with talking, try out [Parenting.StackExchange](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/), be sure to check their rules and guidelines.

Comment: This is the one flaw of the voting system... You can only upvote once, no matter how much you agree. I completely agree with @ardaozkal, especially from personal experience (I was the child, not the parent in this situation), taking something away only makes them want it more.

Comment: I don't know if you guys ever dealt with teenagers....I take it this a flaw that has no real fix/answer? What was Microsoft thinking making a parental control where anyone can just create a new account and bypass everything?

Comment: @InfiniteProgrammer, probably that the kid would only have access to restricted content to.begin with if the parent made it physically available, or gave them a bank card.

Comment: This is not really possible to answer.  Being a teen myself (though at the border of adulthood) i can understand your child learning how to bypass all of the blocks you put in place.  i have actually done some looking into how you can stop your child doing this and haven't found anything that isn't easily bypass able by determined teens.  i defiantly agree with ardaozkal in that talking to your child about why he wants to access such content and why he shouldn't is definitely the best course of action as of this time.

Comment: There needs to be a [tag:parental-controls] tag.

Comment: In the future, I would leave parental advice comments to the parenting SE. This had a technical answer. If you dont know it, dont comment. When someone asks how to mute toxic public chat, we dont suggest they talk it out with the group first and let us know how it went. Somebody asking about parental controls shouldn't get comments about how they raise their kids.

Comment: I agree it's stupid to allow the kid to just create new accounts, what's the point of the parental controls then. Talking to the kids - yeah right. Whoever suggests that has no kids over 11 I'm 100% sure of it.

Answer (score 15):

So I finally found this. If you go into settings, you can select "system" settings. In there you can select "control offline content". In that setting you can uncheck "allow new profiles" and also set the age level for access when no one is signed in and create PassKey to prevent changing those settings. That will control what can be done when no one is signed in and also prevent creating a new profile without the passkey.

Answer (score 6):

All the talking in the world doesn't help some kids.

What you have to do is set up a guest profile with pass key. Then uncheck the box allowing creating new accounts. This will prevent new account creation when not signed in.

Next, make sure your kids' profiles are under your family and then lock down their account how you choose.

This worked on my system.

Answer (score 1):

Something you can do, is stop sharing gold on the account. Xbox One allows gold sharing, which means only one account on the box needs gold for all accounts to benefit. You can find the option in account settings somewhere(sorry, I don't know the exact location... I've never had to turn it off).

I don't know how well this will work, and the kid will be able to just re-enable sharing once he figured out what you did, but it may stall them for a little bit at least.

Overall, the comments are 100% correct. Talk to him about why you are blocking the content in the first place, and be sure yourself when he states his case about why he wants to access it, that's just as important that *you* listen, and try and work out a compromise.

Answer (score 1):

I am in the same position you are. The only guarantee I found that works to keep this from happening is I took the controller away at night.

As far as the talking to your child thing. It sounds like a great idea. Unless you actually have children. Then you would know that this almost never works. As soon as your back is turned they go right back to doing it again. If you have a child that is responsible enough to trust to listen to you, they probably wouldn't be doing this kind of stuff in the first place.

Comment: This is not a real answers to the problem. It rather should be a comment.